# PySide Qt self.function not working in clicked.connect()

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

I am just trying to run a class function when my button is clicked. It works when you write it like this (outside of a class):

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
window =  QtWidgets.QWidget()

def click_me(self):
    print('clicked me!')

button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me")
button1.clicked.connect(click_me)

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(button1)

window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
```

But for some reason the same thing doesn't work when inside a class:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
window =  QtWidgets.QWidget()

class Tester():
    def click_me(self):
        print('clicked me!')

    def run(self):
        button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me")
        button1.clicked.connect(self.click_me)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button1)

        window.setLayout(layout)
        window.show()

Tester().run()
```

Could someone please help me understand why this is the case and how I can fix it. I need the class approach, so I can't just get rid of the class like in my first example.

Note: I am running this in Autodesk Maya, so in my case I don't need to start up a QApplication in my code. I executed the above code by simply pasting it in the Maya terminal and running it.

Comment: You seem to be missing the creation (and exec) of a QApplication in both cases. Please ensure that your examples are reproducible.

Comment: A am using this in Maya where I don't need to add stuff like this. I am not sure what you are referring to?  You can edit my question if you want to add it.

Comment: Ok, for the next time consider specifying it, as it's not implied: for standalone (Py)Qt programs, a QApplication is mandatory, which would make your code not working; Maya already creates a QApplication instance, so it's not required (but we must know about that). That said, is your first code complete as it is? The fact is that, even assuming the above, your first snippet wouldn't work: it would be run, the window would be shown and then immediately closed and deleted because there's no reference to keep it alive.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info I'll add it to my question. Yes it does work 100%, I just tested it now as well to make sure. It creates a window with the button in it, and you can click the button and see the print statement in the console.

Comment: As far as I can understand, everything that should loaded has to be added in some way to `userSetup.py`, is that correct? How did you add your above script, exactly?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. What `userSetup.py` are you referring to? I just pasted this code in the Maya terminal and executed it. That is all :)

Comment: Ah. I thought that the script was loaded in maya (the `userSetup.py` is the file that is used to automatically load custom scripts). You didn't say that the code was running in a terminal, that's a **completely** different thing, and is also another *very* important aspect that you should have mentioned.

Comment: Haha damn sorry man. I'll add that as well. Didn't realise my question had so many loop holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple: the instance has no persistent reference, even in the local scope, so it gets deleted as soon as it's created and its `run` method returns.

The solution is also pretty simple, as you only need to change the last line:

```
tester = Tester()
tester.run()
```

This ensures that the instance has a persistence (setting it to a variable creates a reference), so it will not *garbage collected* (aka: deleted). In your case, the instance were actually deleted after that line, so the `click_me` function (which is an *instance* attribute) gets deleted as well, and so the signal gets automatically disconnected as the object doesn't exist any more.

I believe that you were confused by the fact that many tutorials just call a main function or directly create the instance in a one-liner as you tried.

The difference is that those tutorials create windows that use the maya main window as a parent (which means that it has a reference), and in that case Python does *not* delete them.

In your first example the problem didn't happen because the `click_me` function was anonymous and got referenced in the local scope of the environment.